# Error including files in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I Have 3 wxi files

> IncludesForARIAVersion.wxi :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
     <?include Additional.wxi?>
     <?include Features.wxi?>
 </Include>
```

> Additional.wxi :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <ComponentGroup Id="CMPGRP_Additional.A10">
    <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA10" />
  </ComponentGroup>
  <ComponentGroup Id="CMPGRP_Additional.A11">
    <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA11" />
  </ComponentGroup>
  <ComponentGroup Id="CMPGRP_Additional.v13">
    <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA11" />
  </ComponentGroup>
  <ComponentGroup Id="CMPGRP_Additional.v13.6">
    <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA11" />
  </ComponentGroup>
</Include>
```

> Features.wxi :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature10" Title="$(var.ProductId)" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CMPGRP_Additional.A10" />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature11" Title="$(var.ProductId)" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CMPGRP_Additional.A11" />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature13" Title="$(var.ProductId)" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CMPGRP_Additional.v13" />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature13.6" Title="$(var.ProductId)" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="CMPGRP_Additional.v13.6" />
  </Feature>
</Include>
```

> Product.wxs :

```
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeId)">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Description="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion)" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />

<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1" />
<PropertyRef Id="OSPVersion" />

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<SetProperty Id="INSTALLDLL" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CostInitialize"/>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name='PFiles'>
    <Directory Id="THEFOLDER" Name="Varian">
      <Directory Id="ARIAIC" Name="ARIA IC">
        <Directory Id ="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.ProductId)">
          <Directory Id="HL7Acceptance" Name="acceptance"></Directory>
          <Directory Id="BatchCSIS" Name="batchExportDonneesPourCSIS">
            <Directory Id="scriptBatchCSIS" Name="script"></Directory>
            <Directory Id="exportBatchCSIS" Name="export"></Directory>
          </Directory>
          <Directory Id="Data" Name="data"></Directory>
          <Directory Id="INSTALLDLL" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<?include ../../Shared/setup/IncludesForServerApplication.wxi?>
</Product>
```

> When IncludesForARIAVersion.wxi is added to the product.wxs I Have the error :
>
> error LGHT0204: ICE21: Component: 'CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA10' does not belong to any Feature.
>   error LGHT0204: ICE21: Component: 'CMP_ExportDonneesPourCSISBatA11' does not belong to any Feature.
>
> These components are declare but in Features.wxi. How can i do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Your Features might not be inside your Product element directly or indirectly). Please [edit] your Product element in to your question.